# Put some poses in the list in ROS

Tags: python, ros

I tried to use the class 'geometry_msgs.msg._Pose.Pose' and put a continuously poses in a list by python. Here is what I do:

```
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose
pose = Pose()
list = []
for i in range(5):
    pose.position.z = pose.position.z + 1
    list.append(pose)
```

So I hope the poses in list are a continuous poses corresponding to the value of z from 1 to 5. However the result is that the pose are the same in list......

I am new in both python and ros..... so could anyone please help me ..... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [Udacity](http://forums.udacity.com/questions/8767/python-variables-are-they-really-pointers) post:

The reason this is happening is because you only have one "Pose," and all elements in the list point to it (python pretends to not have pointers, but it really does).  To fix this, you need to generate new poses for each element of the list.

Something like:

```
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose
list = []
for i in range(5):
    pose = Pose()
    if i > 0:
        pose.position.z = list[i - 1].position.z + 1
    list.append(pose)

for item in list:
    print item.position.z
```

will work for you.

Comment: Yeah, it works! Concerning about the pointer in python, do you mean that pose is actually a pointer. So I append that pointer to list?

Comment: Right.  pose is actually pointer to a Pose object behind the scenes.  The link I posted has some good examples of how this works and how to test whether a variable is a reference or not.